"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBase58') when performing chained swap on Solana"
I am working on an arbitrage bot on the Solana blockchain that performs chained swaps using the Jupiter API. I aim to swap from SOL to an intermediate token and then back to SOL in a single transaction.
I have followed the process of obtaining quotes for the swaps and creating the corresponding instructions, but I encounter the following error when trying to execute the chained transaction:
Error during chained swap: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBase58')
    at getOrInsertDefault (/path/to/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/message/compiled-keys.ts:31:30)
    at Function.compile (/path/to/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/message/compiled-keys.ts:51:25)
    at Function.compile (/path/to/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/message/v0.ts:189:39)
    at TransactionMessage.compileToV0Message (/path/to/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction/message.ts:133:22)
    at /path/to/project/src/index.ts:94:10
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/path/to/project/src/index.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Below are the relevant parts of the code I am using:
const connection = new Connection('https://...');

const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(' my keypair as string'));
const wallet = keypair;
async function getQuote(inputMint: string, outputMint: string, amount: number, slippageBps: number) {
  const url = `https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=${inputMint}&outputMint=${outputMint}&amount=${amount}&slippageBps=${slippageBps}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error fetching swap quote: ${response.statusText}`);
  }
  return response.json();
}

async function createSwapInstructions(quoteResponse: any, userPublicKey: string, priorityFee: number): Promise<TransactionInstruction[]> {
  const response = await fetch('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      quoteResponse,
      userPublicKey,
      wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
      computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: priorityFee
    })
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error fetching swap instructions: ${response.statusText}`);
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(data.swapTransaction, 'base64');
  const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

  return transaction.message.compiledInstructions.map((instruction) => {
    return new TransactionInstruction({
      keys: instruction.accountKeyIndexes.map((accountIndex) => ({
        pubkey: transaction.message.staticAccountKeys[accountIndex],
        isSigner: accountIndex < transaction.message.header.numRequiredSignatures,
        isWritable: accountIndex < transaction.message.header.numRequiredSignatures + transaction.message.header.numReadonlySignedAccounts,
      })),
      programId: transaction.message.staticAccountKeys[instruction.programIdIndex],
      data: Buffer.from(instruction.data)
    });
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const inputMint = 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112';
    const intermediateMint = 'some token';
    const amount = 0.01 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
    const slippageBps = 50;
    const priorityFee = 90000;

    const quoteResponse1 = await getQuote(inputMint, intermediateMint, amount, slippageBps);
    const instructions1 = await createSwapInstructions(quoteResponse1, wallet.publicKey.toString(), priorityFee);
    const maxOutAmount = parseInt(quoteResponse1.outAmount);

    const quoteResponse2 = await getQuote(intermediateMint, inputMint, maxOutAmount, slippageBps);
    const instructions2 = await createSwapInstructions(quoteResponse2, wallet.publicKey.toString(), priorityFee);

    const allInstructions = [...instructions1, ...instructions2];
        const quoteResponse1 = await getQuote(inputMint, intermediateMint, amount, slippageBps);
    const instructions1 = await createSwapInstructions(quoteResponse1, wallet.publicKey.toString(), priorityFee);

    const maxOutAmount = parseInt(quoteResponse1.outAmount);

    const quoteResponse2 = await getQuote(intermediateMint, inputMint, maxOutAmount, slippageBps);
    const instructions2 = await createSwapInstructions(quoteResponse2, wallet.publicKey.toString(), priorityFee);

    const allInstructions = [...instructions1, ...instructions2];

    const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: wallet.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
      instructions: allInstructions
    }).compileToV0Message();

    const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
    transaction.sign([keypair]);

    const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, { skipPreflight: true, maxRetries: 2 });

    await connection.confirmTransaction({
      blockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature: txid
    });

    console.log(`Transacción confirmada con ID: ${txid}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error realizando el swap encadenado:', error);
  }
})();



What could be causing the toBase58 error in this context? How can I resolve this issue and successfully perform the chained swap?

Typically this means some code is trying to call toBase58() on a PublicKey, but the actual object is undefined. Take a look and see which of the transaction.message.staticAccountKeys[accountIndex], or transaction.message.staticAccountKeys[instruction.programIdIndex] ends up being undefined
